# Cancel previous request

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, tomcat6, threadpool

For every request, there is a lot of computation happens. On an average the reply takes about 10 minutes to process. Now in the mean time, if a user sends a new request; There is absolutely no point for the previous request to continue.

So I have written a code where I basically interrupt the previous thread executing it. Is it a good practice in tomcat environment? Can there be a better solution to deal with it. Is it alright to interrupt tomcat threads.
Or should I manage my own threadpool and let pool do the computation for me?

---

More Information:
Basically the whole task is wrapped with a FutureTask. For every request, this task is executed and the reference to the task is stored by a ConcurrentHashMap. For every request, all the future's in the map is "cancelled" and then proceeds to execute the latest request. Thus cancelling the previous requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q>** I basically interrupt the previous thread executing it. Is it a good practice in tomcat environment?
**A>** I think it's fine as long as you're happy having HTTP thread(s) blocked for 10 minutes. This means no other user would be able to process HTTP requests. Otherwise create your own thread pool and manage it.

**Q>** Is it a good practice in tomcat environment?
**A>** Interrupting `Runnable`s or `Callable`s can be tricky. For example, if your thread is in the middle of I/O operation, interrupting can leave the data in a corrupt state. Other than that, this is quite normal practice. I also recommend using your own thread pool in order for your server capacity to be predictable.

Can you break your large task into a lot of smaller tasks? Sticking a conditional and exiting early could be a good alternative to interruption.

Alternatively, does waiting for/ensuring the first task finishes the operation and others just return the same value make sense in your environment? If so, I'd rather prefer that instead of your approach. There's `LoadingCache` from guava library which does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks. But isnt maintaining our own threadpool an extra overhead. Where you are using an extra thread for every request. Secondly how does it impact server capacity? I thought tomcat uses a CachedThreadPool with the size of pool increasing based on the requests.

Comment: Well initially I had written the code with a seperate Pool. But later ported it out. There are several advantages of having pool. In a sesnse that you are interrupting a thread which you own and not some random thread. But later ported due to overhead

Comment: You can continue blocking on HTTP thread in case if you don't care that much about varying server capacity. Anyway, I think in the context of 10 minutes per job, creating a new thread has virtually no cost. Or, if you have a static/shared threadpool, the cost is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question completely...

But, if you are talking of running a threadpool within a tomcat application and cancelling its future tasks, I see no problem with that.

I would not interrupt a thread allocated by tomcat, unless I would write code to deal with the interrupt personally (such as within the servlet class)

Comment: Yes I will be dealing with the interrupt status. Basically will throw Interrupted Exception and at right up, will catch exhibiting that the task was cancelled. The only problem with this approach is that: there is no difference between I cancellign the task or threadpoolw as requested to shutdown